# $_post sending blank field data to .php file

Tags: php, forms, email

I have a simple contact form and it works except that the fields data is not sending to the php file when I click submit.
I only get a blank email and I have checked that the variables are empty by printing the `$_post`.
What is wrong? Are the form tag in the wrong place?

PHP-code:

```
<?php
print_r($_POST); exit; /*TO TEST IF THE FIELDS ARE BLANK*/

/* Email Variables */
$emailSubject = 'contactformprocess'; /*Make sure this matches the name of your file*/
$webMaster = 'example@domain.com';


/*design by Mark Leroy @ http://www.helpvid.net*/

/* Data Variables */
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$comments = $_POST['comments'];
if ($name || $email  ||  $phone  ||$comments  == '')
{echo "please fill out required fields";die;}

$body = <<<EOD
<br><hr><br>
Name: $name <br>
Email: $email <br>
Phone: $phone <br>
Comments:\n $comments<br>
EOD;
$headers = "From: $email\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
$success = mail($webMaster, $emailSubject, $body,
$headers);


/* Results rendered as HTML */
$theResults = <<<EOD
<html>
<head>
<title>Meddelandet har skickats</title>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3;URL=http://www.website.com/">
<style type="text/css";>
<!--
body {
background-color: #444; /* You can edit this CSS to match your website*/
font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 20px;
font-style: normal;
line-height: normal;
font-weight: normal;
color: #fec001;
text-decoration: none;
padding-top: 200px;
margin-left: 150px;
width: 800px;
}
-->
</style>
</head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<div align="center">Tack för din förfrågan! Vi hör av oss så fort som möjligt.</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
EOD;
echo "$theResults";
?>
```

HTML-code: (the website is only one page so here's a part of the code where the form is located.

```
    <!--contact start-->
          <form id="emailform" name="emailform" method="post" action="contactformprocess.php">
    <div id="contact">
        <div class="line5">                 
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row Ama">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                    <h3>Behöver du hjälp?</h3>
                    <p>Hör av dig till oss!</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-9 col-xs-12 forma">
<input type="text" class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 name" input name="name" id="name" placeholder='Namn *'/>
                  <input type="text" class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 phone" id="phone" input name="phone" placeholder='Telefon *'/>
                  <input type="text" class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 email" input name="email" id="email" placeholder='Email *'/>
                  <textarea type="text" class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 comments" textarea name="comments" placeholder='Meddelande *' id="comments"></textarea>
                  <div class="cBtn col-xs-12">
                      <ul>
                        <li class="send"><a href="/contactformprocess.php" onclick="validateForm()" title="submit">Skicka</a></li>
                          <p><br>
                        </p>
                    </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
              </div>
              </form>
```

**UPDATE 1**
Thanks the data is now sending correctly when I added the

```
  <div class="cBtn col-xs-12">
      <ul>
        <li class="send">  <input type="submit"  onclick="validateForm()" title="submit">Skicka</a></li>
```

[image: design issue]

Comment: You have a repeating `input` string in your `<input>` tags, just before `name` attribute

Comment: Show function `validateForm()`. This function is called on click event of your validation link. If this function doesn't exists or doesn't submit form, user will be redirected to `contactformprocess.php` without form data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the JavaScript `validateForm()` function doesn't explicitly *submit* the form data, you will need to use a submit button. This would mean, instead of the following:

```
<a href="/contactformprocess.php" onclick="validateForm()" title="submit">Skicka</a>
```

use a submit button:

```
<input type="submit" onclick="validateForm()" value="Skicka" />
```

The submit button is what tells the browser to send all of the data in `<input>` and similar tags to the server; a simple HTML link is not aware of any forms, unless some special JavaScript is fired.

---

A few other comments are here below.

**Input name:** Don't use `input name` but `name` inside of `<input>`, like this snippet below:

```
<input type="text" class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 phone" id="phone" name="phone" placeholder='Telefon *'/>
```

instead of the `input name` that is in your code:

```
<input type="text" class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 phone" id="phone" input name="phone" placeholder='Telefon *'/>
```

**Form validation:** The following will do the opposite of what you want:

```
if ($name || $email  ||  $phone  ||$comments  == '')
{echo "please fill out required fields";die;}
```

It should be something like this:

```
if (!$name || !$email  || !$phone  || $comments  == '')
{echo "please fill out required fields";die;}
```

It's still not the best form of validation, but at least it won't cause an error exactly when it shouldn't.

Comment: He can submit form by a link : on click event, `validateForm()` function is call and this function can submit form.

Comment: @djidi Correct, thanks. I ruled that out because of the "validate" part in the name, but I've updated my post to mention that assumption.

Comment: @ljacqu the <input type="submit" did work but now the design of the button is all messed up, i will update with a picture.

Comment: @Tibbe What code are you using now? You should remove the HTML link, of course. (Hard to tell if "Skicka" or "Submit" is a HTML link with a lot of styling from an image)

Comment: @ljacqu look at the update which code I have now, but it only works when I click on the "submit" button

Comment: @Tibbe Change `<input type="submit"  onclick="validateForm()" title="submit">Skicka</a>` to `<input type="submit" onclick="validateForm()" value="Skicka" title="submit" />`. To set the text of the submit button, you use `<input value="Text">` and not `<input>Text</input>` and certainly not `<input>Text</a>`

Comment: @ljacqu okey, so i will just need to edit the button by my self so it looks like the old one? because the old one is just laying under and if you click on it nothing happens.

Comment: @Tibbe Yeah, the input button will need some styling with CSS if you want to change its appearance :)

Comment: @ljacqu thanks man! I used form.submit() in the onclick function and i could preserve the design!

Answer (score 0):

When defining an input field, you don't have to type "input" before the name tag, as you already defined it when opening the tag. Remove those.
So, instead of

```
<input type="text" class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 name" input name="name" id="name" placeholder='Namn *'/>
<input type="text" class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 phone" id="phone" input name="phone" placeholder='Telefon *'/>
<input type="text" class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 email" input name="email" id="email" placeholder='Email *'/>
```

try with the following:

```
<input type="text" class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 name" name="name" id="name" placeholder='Namn *'/>
<input type="text" class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 phone" id="phone" name="phone" placeholder='Telefon *'/>
<input type="text" class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 email" name="email" id="email" placeholder='Email *'/>
```

and check if it makes any difference.
 tag itself is fine. It just tells the server to process everything inside the FORM scope after clicking Submit.